# Windows XP takes over 5 minutes "saving settings" on logout or shutdown

Tags: windows-xp

**SOLVED: Uphclean fixed the problem**

Basically the comp in question is taking ages to log out - but only from the main account. I tried creating another account on the system and it only took seconds to log out. However, there seems to be no specific reason for this. Could it be that the registry is fragmented or something? How would I test what the problem is?

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that this has been happening for quite long now. The computer is not usually used by me. Also, there are no problems logging in, only logging out.

Comment: is this a domain joined workstation with roaming profiles?

Comment: This is a common desktop computer

Comment: as in its a home computer? If so I'd suspect that ntuser.dat file is corrupt. Another idea is microsoft has uphclean application that you can download, I install it on all xp workstations it can speed up some log off issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded uphclean and rebooted the computer. Suddenly saving settings only took around half a second.

Thanks, smoknheap.

Comment: yea uphclean should be mandatory for windows xp!

Answer (score 1):

I would start by taking a look at the processes that are running before you log out of each user profile.

Compare the list of processes running for the slow profile, against the profile which works properly. It's unlikely to be a Service that's making it slow, as they run regardless of the logged in user.

You may be able to get a good idea by looking at the HKLU/Software/Microsoft/Current Version/Run key in the registry whilst logged in as the user having issues, and see what software's listed there. That will list all the programs which startup for that specific user, and if there's something in there for that user and not the others, that'll probably be what's slowing it down.

I think it's unlikely that registry fragmentation is causing it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this has been happening for quite long now. The computer is not usually used by me. Also, there are no problems logging in, only logging out.

Comment: So have you checked the processes running on exit?

Comment: Not yet. I'm currently checking if any of the services could be causing this, using the internets as a source of information.